# how to resume main activity while going back from another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-cursoradapter

In my application first activity having one listview which take data from sqlite database . on click any item it start another activity but coming back it is not resume the main activity I don't know how ?
Can anyone suggest me best answare in this regard . I have google a lot .
Starting new activity from main activity :

```js
   
        intent = new Intent(this, second_activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Response", message);
        intent.putExtra("Ip_address", IP_DB);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and my second activity is :

```js
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        }
         public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent i=new Intent(this, HOME_AUTOMATION.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not resuming the activity? Is your onCreate being fired again or when you press the back button your are taken to your launcher screen?

Comment: what do you mean by it is not resume the main activity ? If you are not seeing main activity on back press, you probabily finishing the main activity while starting another activity. please eloborate question or paste code snippet of how you are starting another activity and the code if you have any in onBackPressed() of another activity.

Comment: I think you are finishing your activity when you launch the new one on item click.

Comment: can anyone answer this ?

Comment: yes Wilson onCreate being fired again when I press the back button .

Comment: You should change the implementation , don't finish the `FirstActivity` while moving to `SecondActivity` then you don't need to override `onKeyDown` to launch the `FirstActivity` again. System will automatically resume your `FirstActivity` when you press Back button on `SecondActivity`.